# Fragments, ActionBarSherlock and Menus

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the ActionBarSherlock library and fragments. However, I'm having a very hard time getting menus to show up on the screen after the 2nd fragment comes up.
It's a very simple program with 1 screen following another. I use a FragmentTransaction and I replace each time. I use setHasOptionsMenu(true) in each fragment. 
The onCreateOptionsMenu & onPrepareOptionsMenu are getting called but I've got a blank area where the menu is. I can select that area and it seems to work but no text.
Any ideas?
Fragment code:

```
public class MyListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {  
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);  
}  
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        if (menu.findItem(R.id.save) == null) {
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.new_menu, menu);
        }
    }
```

Activity:

```
public class MyMain extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        handler = new Handler();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Fragment code

```
fragmentEntries.push(stackEntry);
FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(contentId, fragment, fragmentName);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Can you post code for Activity and Fragment?

Comment: To add a fragment, I simply use:      fragmentEntries.push(stackEntry);  
  FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();  
  ft.replace(contentId, fragment, fragmentName);  
  ft.commit();    The activity is just a SherlockFragmentActivity  The Fragment puts `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the onCreate

Answer (score 0):

onCreateOptionsMenu will only get called once per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)..

> After the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu(), it retains an instance of the Menu you populate and will not call onCreateOptionsMenu() again unless the menu is invalidated for some reason. However, you should use onCreateOptionsMenu() only to create the initial menu state and not to make changes during the activity lifecycle.
>
> If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items. (Fragments also provide an onPrepareOptionsMenu() callback.)

Comment: I'm doing all that. When I debug and look at the Menu, it has all my items but it is not displaying. I noticed that when I debugged, my menu would show up until I called menuItem.setVisible(true) and then it disappeared.

Comment: Where is this code in the code presented above? Could you please add _anything_ you do with regards to the menu/actionbar?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was just a dumb mistake. I had a menu with an icon (that was a selector) that seemed to obscure the text.
My test also failed because I was using menus that had items with the same id.